# Subsetting and averaging in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset and average specific values in a data frame that I got by reading in a csv file.

I have a dataframe that has several variables, and I want to average different subsets and compare them to each other using ggplot.

dummy example:

```
            Sample input lot gene count 
       1       1    50   6    A    10   
       2       1    50   6    A    11   
       3       1    50   6    B   100  
       4       1    50   6    B   112   
       5       1  1000   7    A    12   
       6       1  1000   7    A    13   
       7       1  1000   7    B   150   
       8       1  1000   7    B   151  
       9       2    50   6    A   660   
       10      2    50   6    A   661   
       11      2    50   6    B  2000   
       12      2    50   6    B  2002   
       13      2  1000   7    A   662   
       14      2  1000   7    A   663   
       15      2  1000   7    B  2250   
       16      2  1000   7    B  2252
```

What I am trying to do is get the average counts of replicates for each **input** per **sample**, per **lot**, per **gene**. So in this example the average would be:

Sample 1-input 50-gene A = 10.5

Then I want to create a new column with those averages that is for the input averaged, and a column for the "standard" which in this case would be 1000.

```
            Sample input lot gene count avg.each avg.1000
       1       1    50   6    A    10     10.5     12.5
       2       1    50   6    A    11     10.5     12.5
       3       1    50   6    B   100    106.0    150.5
       4       1    50   6    B   112    106.0    150.5
       5       1  1000   7    A    12     12.5     12.5
       6       1  1000   7    A    13     12.5     12.5
       7       1  1000   7    B   150    150.5    150.5
       8       1  1000   7    B   151    150.5    150.5
       9       2    50   6    A   660    660.5    662.5
       10      2    50   6    A   661    660.5    662.5
       11      2    50   6    B  2000   2001.0   2251.0
       12      2    50   6    B  2002   2001.0   2251.0
       13      2  1000   7    A   662    662.5    662.5
       14      2  1000   7    A   663    662.5    662.5
       15      2  1000   7    B  2250   2251.0   2251.0
       16      2  1000   7    B  2252   2251.0   2251.0
```

So then I can plot avg.each against the "standard" avg.1000. In my actual work, I have a lot more replicates, more input amounts, more genes, and samples. I was going about it by assigning the subsets to new variables and finding averages of all the subsets. But it just seemed so clunky. Anyone have any better advice???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused about your question, but I think you need to use the package `dplyr`, as follows:

```
# Create example data.frame
df <- data_frame(
   sample = rep(c(1,2), each = 8),
   input  = rep(rep(c(50,1000), each = 4), 2),
   lot    = rep(rep(c(6,7), each = 4), 2),
   gene   = rep(rep(c("A","B"), each = 2), 4),
   count  = sample(100, size = 16)
)

# Average of counts
df1 <- df %>% 
   group_by(sample, input, lot, gene) %>% 
   mutate(avg.each = mean(count))

# Standard average
standard <- 1000
df2 <- df %>% 
   filter(input == standard) %>% 
   group_by(sample, gene) %>% 
   summarize(avg.1000 = mean(count))

# Combine data.frames
df3 <- df1 %>% 
   left_join(df2, by = c("sample", "gene"))
```

So, you need to create two temporary `data.frames` and combine them using the `left_join` function. Take a look at the temporary `data.frames` to understand what I did. I hope this can help you!

Comment: I used the below suggestion and your join to put it all together, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified form of what you are looking for:

```
df<-read.table(header= TRUE, text = "Sample input lot gene count 
              1    50   6    A    10   
              1    50   6    A    11   
              1    50   6    B   100  
              1    50   6    B   112   
              1  1000   7    A    12   
              1  1000   7    A    13   
              1  1000   7    B   150   
              1  1000   7    B   151  
              2    50   6    A   660   
              2    50   6    A   661   
              2    50   6    B  2000   
              2    50   6    B  2002   
              2  1000   7    A   662   
              2  1000   7    A   663   
              2  1000   7    B  2250   
              2  1000   7    B  2252")

library(dplyr)
myave<-df %>% group_by(Sample, input, gene) %>%
  summarize(mcount = mean(count))

library(tidyr)
spread(myave, input, mcount)
```

This summarizes the sample data down to 4 lines.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for!